# AngularJS - interval doesn't get flushed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-mock

I have the angular service function that I am willing to test:

```
doSomeTask: function (ids, callback) {
  $http.put('/get_job', {'ids': ids}).success(function (data) {
    var statusCheck = $interval(function() {
      $http.get('check_status?=' + data.job_id).success(function (data) {
        if(data.completed) {
          $interval.cancel(statusCheck);
          // and do something...
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
```

And the following test for it:

```
describe('MyService', function() {

  var myService;
  var $httpBackend;
  var $interval;

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _$interval_, $rootScope, MyService) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $interval = _$interval_;
    myService  = MyService;
  }));

  describe('doSomeTask', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      $httpBackend.expectPUT("/get_job").respond({ job_id: '123' });
      $httpBackend.expectGET("/status_check").respond({ completed: true });
    });

    it('should do it well', inject(function ($interval) {    
      var ids = [1,2,3];
      myService.doSomeTask(ids);

      $httpBackend.flush();
      $interval.flush();
    }));
  });
});
```

It seems like my interval never gets flushed (the second expectation never get satisfied and my breakpoints inside the interval body never fired).  It also seems like I am using the mock (placed some commend in flush implementation).  The versions of Angular and mocks are the same...

What am I doing wrong?  How can I flush my interval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to call a second `$httpBackend.flush()` after you flush your interval. Test if you get the console output when doing a log at this place of your code:

```
doSomeTask: function (ids, callback) {
  $http.put('/get_job', {'ids': ids}).success(function (data) {
    var statusCheck = $interval(function() {
      console.log("flushed");
      $http.get('check_status?=' + data.job_id).success(function (data) {
        if(data.completed) {
          $interval.cancel(statusCheck);
          // and do something...
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
```

When you get a `flushed` in your console, then call a second `$httpBackend.flush()` and the second http request gets fired.

```
it('should do it well', inject(function ($interval) {    
  var ids = [1,2,3];
  myService.doSomeTask(ids);

  $httpBackend.flush();
  $interval.flush();
  // after this call, you should get a 'flushed' in your console
  $httpBackend.flush();
  // after this call, the second http should fire
}));
```

## Solution:

To flush an interval, specify the amount of milliseconds you want to flush like this: `$interval.flush(2000)`

Comment: Have tried that.  It is exactly what i expect to see, 'flushed'.  But it just doesn't happen.  Consequently, if I flush $httpBackend again i'm getting 'no pending request' error...

Comment: So, you see the output of `console.log("flushed");` in your console?

Comment: Think I figured out... flush has to have a number of milliseconds specified.  When i did it got flushed and all good times!

Comment: I've updated my answer, so that future readers get a quick solution without reading the comments.

Comment: This was awesome. Not sure why $interval requires you to put in the actual milliseconds while $timeout doesn't. Maybe it was just me but didn't find anything in documentation around this?